# comparing strings in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have file content like this

```
XXX,AAAAAA,B,CC;Cont 123456;2.50;1;1;1;2;0;1;l;
XXX,AAAAAA,B,CC;Avboo;1.20;1;1;1;2;0;1;l;
XXX,AAAAAA,B,CC;Dartw esata garle;3.00;1;1;1;2;0;1;ccc;
```

file is saved in c:\myFile.txt

in my nunit test I'm trying to create exact strings as is inside file content and after that I want to assert that are equal

```
[Test]
public void test()
{      
   string line1 = "XXX,AAAAAA,B,CC;Cont 123456;2.50;1;1;1;2;0;1;l;\r\n";
   string line2 = "XXX,AAAAAA,B,CC;Avboo;1.20;1;1;1;2;0;1;l;\r\n";
   string line3 = "XXX,AAAAAA,B,CC;Dartw esata garle;3.00;1;1;1;2;0;1;ccc;\r\n";    
   string expected = string.Concat(line1,line2,line3);
   var fileContent = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\myFile.txt");
   Assert.AreEqual(fileContent, expected);
}
```

Althout it's looks like that it should be exact strings I'm getting error

> Excpected string length 149 but was 154. Strings differ at index 86

Comment: Did you look at them in the debugger to see what the difference at index 86 is?

Comment: Have you checked what is coming out of `File.ReadAllText()`?

Comment: You probably need to add a `@` char in front of your expected strings, i.e. `string line1 = @"XXX...";`

Comment: Have you tried to remove \r ? What is the encoding of myFile.txt ?

Comment: you could write multiline text without anything, just use `+` at the end, example: string expected = "..." + (next line) "...".

Comment: @Sinatr - Than't not multiline text; that's string concatenation.

Comment: instead of "\r\n", use Environment.NewLine. The error may be the last newline (no at the end of file)

Comment: @KennethK., yes, right. I should call it differently, but "multiline" was first what comes to my mind and I didn't think about omitting `\n\r`, I mean what you don't need 3 variables and call to `string.Concat` when you can define variable with use of same 3 rows of source code. Btw, an idea, shouldn't you use `\n\r` instead of `\r\n` ???

Comment: @Sinatr Windows uses `\r\n` for delimiting newlines; *nix uses simply `\n`. [Info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if you remove the last line break:

```
 string line3 = "XXX,AAAAAA,B,CC;Dartw esata garle;3.00;1;1;1;2;0;1;ccc;";
```

I think the end of your text file is not a line break.

Comment: This is the most possible reason for difference in length. And regarding mismatch, it is that strange symbol (letter?) `l` which may looks like digit `1` and you may have been mistyped it.

Comment: This is a good and correct answer, specific to an error in the test. But doesn't really address the core issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385301/comparing-strings-in-c-sharp/15385736#15385736

Answer (score 2):

Use `Environment.NewLine` instead of `\r\n`.

Answer (score 1):

The message you got is explicit:

`Expected string length 149 but was 154. Strings differ at index 86`

It points at the `\r\n` location ; So I suspect your file contains `\n` and not `\r` and `\n` together.

```
                                  position 86: \r found |
                                                        v
...;1;1;1;2;0;1;l;XXX,AAAAAA,B,CC;Avboo;1.20;1;1;1;2;0;1;l;XXX,AAAAAA,B,CC;
```

- For this reason, the file comparaison differs because there is a unexpected \r at the position 86.

So you have now 3 extra chars.

Because your text file does probably not end with `\r\n`, now you have one more extra chars:

- That's the reason why you have a total of 5 extra chars (4 + an extra char I did not spot yet) : 154 instead of 149.

Answer (score 0):

You have an **extra NewLineChar** in `line3`, the following code works correctly:

```
[Test]
public void test()
{
    string line1 = "XXX,AAAAAA,B,CC;Cont 123456;2.50;1;1;1;2;0;1;l;\r\n";
    string line2 = "XXX,AAAAAA,B,CC;Avboo;1.20;1;1;1;2;0;1;l;\r\n";
    string line3 = "XXX,AAAAAA,B,CC;Dartw esata garle;3.00;1;1;1;2;0;1;ccc;";
    string expected = string.Concat(line1, line2, line3);
    var fileContent = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\myFile.txt");
}
```

Also you can add an extra NewLineChar in your `myfile.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Another approach.

```
var actual = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\abc.txt");
var expected = new List<string>();
expected.Add("line1");
expected.Add("line2");
expected.Add("line3");
Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```

Or you can do a for loop on the list and check each line one by one.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of good answers on here as to how better do the test. But in fact there are two fundemental issues with the question.

1. it's not a unit test, it's an integration test
2. If you don't know what the .NET String output of the file is in the first place, the test is pointless. You need to find this out first.

To do this I would first debug the test and copy the output of `File.ReadAllText("[filename]");` Then paste this output into your `Assert.` method/s.

One of the main keys to unit / integration testing is to know exactly what both sides of your test **are**. Without this, you might as well not bother.

Also, what are you testing?